# Facebook Share button showing name at bottom of feed

Tags: facebook, share, feed, facebook-sharer

I am having issue while sharing content from my website to facebook. posting picture that will explain every thing and below is the share link which m using to post content to facebook.

[Share Link](https://web.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=505015129702076&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgharplans.com%2Finterior_detail%2F6%2FKitchen-in-Pakistan&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button&_rdr)

[error message while posting content from website to facebook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PquEe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta name="author" content="Mosaddek">` on those pages is causing the name to appear on the share link. Edit your template, remove that line and it should no longer appear on Facebook shares.

Comment: thanks a lot. its really there in my header. i was checking all over developer.facebook.com and i was wrong. Thank a lot again.

Comment: hello @Tom Im facing the same issue and can not resolve it, if im removing <meta name="author"> and i post just link to facebook im getting that name. link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fURG.png )